# docker-compose autorestart and supervisord autorestart : which to use?

Tags: docker

I ve seen in some build the use of supervisor to run the `docker-compose up -d` command with the possibility to autostart and/or autorestart.

Im wondering if this cohabitation of supervisor and docker-compose works well? Aren't the two autorestart options interfering with each other? Also what is the benefit to use supervisor in place of a simple docker-compose except run at startup if the server is shut down?

Please share your experience if you have some on using theses two tools

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Running multiple single-process containers is almost always better than running a single multiple-process container; avoid supervisord when possible.

Mechanically, the combination should work fine.  Supervisord will capture logs and take responsibility for restarting the process in the container.  That means `docker logs` will have no interesting output, and you need to get the file content out of the container.  If one of the managed processes fails then supervisord will restart it.  The container itself will probably never be restarted, unless supervisord manages to crash somehow.

There are a couple of notable disadvantages to using supervisord:

- As noted, it swallows logs, so you need a complex file-oriented approach to read them out.
- If one of the processes fails then you'll have difficulty seeing that from outside the container.
- If you have a code update you have to delete and recreate the container with the new image, which with supervisord means restarting every process.
- In a clustered environment like Kubernetes, every process in the supervisord container runs on the same node, and you can't scale individual processes up to handle additional load.

Given the choice of tools you suggest, I'd pretty much always use Compose with its `restart:` policies, and not use supervisord at all.

Comment: thanks a lot for your feedback. I was mainly considering using supervisor to run the docker-compose up command actually, i didnt think about using supervisor inside the container...

Comment: Aha.  The same basic considerations still apply: Docker knows how to restart containers and manage logs on its own, so you don't necessarily need an init system with the same functionality.  It can make sense to launch a Docker container (or group of containers) under an init system for other reasons (reproducibility, consistency with other services, clearer startup-time behavior) but that's not really a programming-oriented question.